# When do local GPOs apply if a computer is a part of a domain?

Tags: windows, domain, group-policy, active-directory, local

when do local GPOs apply if a computer is a part of a domain? What would be an example scenario when local GPOs would be relevant for a computer that is a part of a domain?
Can I somehow 'use' local GPOs even if the computer is a part of the domain?

I ask because I want to understand the difference between local GPOs and domain GPOs and how they differ / how they are interrelated.

Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Local policies apply ***first***; this means that their settings apply to the system, but are overridden by a setting from a linked domain GPO at any level.

Essentially, it's the lowest precedence location in which policies can be applied.  You can set whatever you want, as long as no domain policy sets the same thing.

Take a gander [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785665%28WS.10%29.aspx) for lots more information on GPO processing order.

Comment: Group Policy processing occurs in the following order: LSDOU = Local, Site, Domain, OU.

Comment: @joeqwerty Major extra nerd points if you've got a mnemonic for that.

Comment: All People Seem To Need Data Processing... wait... that's for something else... but what?... can't remember...